How to use try-catch (IOException) for BufferedWriter.write nested in if-else?
I have a block to write data(string) using BufferedWriter, but compiler keeps saying error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown this.dataContainer.stream().forEach( line -> writer.write(line) );
The BufferWriter.write() is already inside a try-catch block.
Is the error caused by it nested inside if-else?
How shall it be written?
void saveData() throws IOException {
        
String filename;
Path filePath; 
BufferedWriter writer;
    
filename = "missionImpossible9.csv";
filePath = this.dirPath.resolve(filename); //make path of this file
writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(filePath); 
        
try {
    if (condition1) {
       this.dataContainer1.stream().forEach( line -> writer.write(line) );
     } else {
       this.dataContainer2.stream().forEach( line -> writer.write(line) );
     }
     writer.close();
} catch (IOException err){
    err.getStackTrace();}
}


Change that to try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(filePath))) { ... And printStackTrace btw

By the way, there is a Files.write method which writes a sequence of lines to a file, without your having to create a Writer.  As in, Files.write(filePath, this.dataContainer1);.

@VGR Files.write() was also raised by Holger. It looks like it takes a Path and an Iterable (ArrayList, Queue, etc), and it will loop through it automatically and write out item by item?

Yes.  It’s not identical to your code, since your code does not write a newline after each line.  I’m not sure if that was intentional.

@VGR thanks, it works better. Each data element in my example dataContainer is csv with newline included.

The problem is that the method write() of BufferedWriter is declared as throwing IOException, but you're calling it inside a Consumer<?> (the .forEach()) which is not supposed to throw any checked exception:
this.dataContainer1.stream().forEach( line -> writer.write(line) );

The expression line -> writer.write(line) is a lambda expression implementing the functional interface Consumer, and you can't throw checked exceptions (such as IOException) inside a lambda.
The way to solve the issue is to catch the IOException inside the lambda itself, and rethrow it wrapped into a RuntimeException (which is unchecked):
this.dataContainer1.stream().forEach(line -> {
        try {
            writer.write(line); //try code that throws a checked exception
        } catch (IOException e) { //catch that checked exception
            throw new RuntimeException(e); //rethrow it as the cause of a runtime (unchecked) exception
        }
    });

At this point you don't need to catch IOException any longer (in any case, if an IOException occurs from write() you will receive it as a RuntimeException having cause that IOException.
Note: there are nicer ways to keep the type IOException without the compiler complaining, which is called Sneaky Throw. You may want to read this article about it: Sneaky throws article.
Generally speaking it's not suggested to silent a checked exception like this, but sometimes there's no other choice (for example when you want to run code inside a lambda expression and you need to use a functional interface that doesn't throw, such as Consumer).

thank you. Never thought a checked exception cannot occur inside forEach(). In that case, many IO operations are not suitable to take place inside a stream?

There's UncheckedIOException right there, you should be using that instead of RuntimeException. More generally the obvious solution here is not to use forEach. Lambdas aren't transparent in 3 ways (locals, control flow, checked exceptions) - if that is annoying (and it tends to be), do not use them. Just use a while loop.

@rzwitserloot It doesn't change much, the real exception is IOException, rethrowing the one you said rather than any other runtime will behave the same in terms of flow (you dont déclare it in the signature) and if you are logging you will still see the original IOException in the logs. As for lambdas, as long as you create/use a sneaky throw construct you can keep on using lambdas without too much overhead. I agree that sometimes you can just opt for using standard loops but when these loops become complex, the stream API makes the code more readable at my taste

The variable name line suggests that actually writing lines is intended. In this case, use the right tool for the job: Files.write(filePath, dataContainer1); Files.write(filePath, dataContainer2, StandardOpenOption.APPEND); Then, no wrapping of exceptions is required. But if you are wrapping IOException in a runtime exception, using UncheckedIOException is preferable, not because of what you see in logs when the exception is not caught, but because it allows catching it and rethrowing the IOException, as the method has been declared as throws IOException…

@Holger my data are stored in a LinkedList (dataContainer), so need to loop through it and write each element (line) one by one. The Files.write() you suggested takes an Iterable as argument and will iterate the Collection automatically? Never used it before.

Yes, that’s what it does.

@Holger has the right idea. Otherwise, limestreetlab, where are your line separators coming from?

@Holger I'm not saying you're wrong, there clearly are better ways to do what OP wants to do. But let's not forget the question was about "why is the compiler still telling me to catch IOException" and the answer is what I wrote. But I agree with you, there are many other better ways to write lines into a file

@MatteoNNZ of course it changes much. You've removed 'deal with it' from the menu. You can't catch RuntimeException meaningfully unless you go out of you way to 'unhack' this 'hack' (get the cause and instanceof or pattern match on it, which is just digging deeper. What did while ever do to you that you ruin a codebase with stream() just to spite it so?) - or you're catching everything (endpoint runners can do that). UncheckedIOException is at least more meaningfully catchable.

@MatteoNNZ Your sensibilities are off. It's somewhat common: "Oh, look, streams. This code is CLEAN. And any code that doesn't is UGLY". This is highly misleading, and makes you write very difficult to test and maintain code. Such as just so very casually tossing out any ability to write meaningful catches. Or just being blind to what's happening. See Holger's comment, for example. This answer does not 'just' answer the question. It also is opinionated on how to deal with it. And that opinion is wrong. Or at least, highly suspect.

@rzwitserloot if you want to open a dispute stream vs loop I stop you there: I never write streams unless I have to do basic things, because they are slower, impossible to debug, impose you final variables and can't throw checked exceptions, which is the only way I have to explicitly inform the caller that something may go wrong. But then again: the OP asked why the catch of IOException didn't work, and I explained it was because of the lambda in the forEach. I never said that was the best approach to do what he's doing, I was just answering a question

@rzwitserloot concerning Unchecked IOException: it still is a runtime exception. Of course you can catch it, but the compiler won't tell you. It won't tell you even if you declare it in the throws list of the method. So either you know you have to catch it (and in that case you can use sneaky throw as i suggested and avoid any useless wrapping), or you will miss it the same way you would miss any other runtime exception, which is by definition not thought to be caught but to flow up until a global catch Throwable handler point

@g00se thanks, each line in my data has a newline separator already

Thanks both @rzwitserloot and MatteroNNZ. Let's say both of you have good ideas and stop there?

@limestreetlab you're nice to worry but we're not arguing, these are just discussions among developers :) rzwitserloot is right in many things he said, namely using streams (which is often abused by thinking it's cleaner) as well as wrapping exceptions into RuntimeException. Again, I've answered your question as is. If you ask me the solution I'd go for, is the one proposed by g00se and not the fix I proposed above (which again, is just the answer to your question and not THE answer to your problem).

@MatteoNNZ yes, your answer was addressing the OP’s literal question. That’s why your post is an answer and mine just a comment. I usually prefer to include both aspects in an answer in such situations, to help understanding the problem and finding a (better) solution. I like this old article about the dilemma.

Just to make it quite plain how clean Holger's solution is:
    void saveData() throws IOException {
        String filename;
        Path filePath;
        boolean condition1 = false;
        Path dirPath = Path.of("/tmp");
        filename = "missionImpossible9.csv";
        filePath = dirPath.resolve(filename);

        if (condition1) {
            Files.write(filePath, dataContainer1);
        } else {
            Files.write(filePath, dataContainer2);
        }
    }


Or even Files.write(filePath, condition1? dataContainer1: dataContainer2);
